# Difference in performance between interpolation {{}} and [innerText] - angular 2

Tags: angularjs, performance, angular

In Angular 1 using `ng-bind` gave you a performance boost over interpolation.

Is this still the case in Angular 2? Should I use `[innerText]` over interpolation.

E.g.

```
<p>{{slower}}</p>
<p [innerText]="faster"></p>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> We often have a choice between interpolation and property binding. The following binding pairs do the same thing:
>
> ```
> Interpolated: <img src="{{vehicle.imageUrl}}"><br>
> Property bound: <img [src]="vehicle.imageUrl">
>
> The interpolated title is {{title}}
>
> [innerHTML]="'The [innerHTML] title is '+title">
> ```
>
> Interpolation is a convenient alternative for property binding in many cases. In fact, Angular translates those interpolations into the corresponding property bindings before rendering the view.
>
> There is no technical reason to prefer one form to the other. We lean toward readability, which tends to favor interpolation. We suggest establishing coding style rules and choosing the form that both conforms to the rules and feels most natural for the task at hand.

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding

So you can use anyone. Hope this will help you.

Comment: There is a main difference though. `{{}}` is interpolation, which means the value will be stringified first. Therefore don't use `{{}}` if you want to pass something that is not a string (like an object or array).

Answer (score 0):

> You can use anyone. But I think, Property binding is faster as Angular
>   translates interpolations into the corresponding property bindings
>   before rendering view. So if you use property binding then Angular
>   does not need that translations.